# How to disable all thumbnail previews except images?

Tags: finder, macos

New to Mac.  I'm trying to find a way to stop showing thumbnails for files.  With documents, I want to see the icon for the *type* of file it is (word, spreadsheet, database, etc) because I work with files in multiple formats, so it's easiest for me to find them this way.

However, disabling that in Finder also disables showing image thumbnails.  I *do* want to see image thumbnails because it's easier to find them that way, obviously.

How can I make it so that I see image thumbnails, but other files are normal icons? Basically, I'd like it to work like File Managers do in Windows and Linux.  How can I do this on my Mac?

Comment: I think there is no way (yet) to turn previews for one specific file types only. It's either `on` or `off` for all files.

Comment: I would also consider using an alternative file manager that has this ability...

Comment: I am not sure about this exactly feature, but the most advanced File Manager I have ever used was [Path Finder 7](https://cocoatech.com/#/). Try it, they have 30 days fully functional trial, probably you'll find required settings.